# Insert image path in remote database in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am developing Android application that should save and get an image from remote database.

How to insert into remote database (MySQL) a path of a photo that I select from Gallery.

I know how to select a photo from Gallery and set it on a image view. But how to insert the path into the database? and how to get the photo?

Answer (score 0):

use the following link to get the image path 
           http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-when-select.html.

then you can use http post to store the path in database.